# angular2 - communication between components

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I search about communication between components with Angular2, but what I need is a little bit different.
I have a structure like this:

Father --> Son --> Son

My Code looks like this

Father Component:

```ts
@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: './instituicao/components/instituicao.html',
directives: [InstituicaoForm, InstituicaoList]
})

export class InstituicaoCmp {}
```

My instituicao.html

```ts
<instituicao-form>
    <div class="row">
        <instituicao-list></instituicao-list>
    </div>
</instituicao-form>
```

I just have a form at `<instituicao-form>` that I want to populate when user clicks at some item of table list from `<instituicao-list>`
Something like this at `<instituicao-list>`:

```ts
<tr role="row" *ngFor="#item of items | instituicaoPipe : searchItems">
          <td>{{item.id.idInstituicao}}</td>
          <td>{{item.descInstituicao}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="HERE I WANT TO POPULATE FORM AT INSTITUICAO-FORM COMPONENT(item)"> Editar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

My instituicao-form html is just a form with some fields like `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.idInstituicao"`

I only could do this using ng-model at `<instituicao-form>` 
and putting my list at `<instituicao-form>` too.

Please someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I assume you want something like this:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [InstituicaoForm, InstituicaoList],
  template: `
  <instituicao-form #form>
    <div class="row">
      <instituicao-list (selectionChanged)="#form.update($event)></instituicao-list>
    </div>
  </instituicao-form>`,
})
export class InstituicaoCmp {
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'instituicao-list',
  template: `
    <tr role="row" *ngFor="#item of items | instituicaoPipe : searchItems">
      <td>{{item.id.idInstituicao}}</td>
      <td>{{item.descInstituicao}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="select(item)"> Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>`,
})
export class InstituicaoList {
  var items;
  @Output() selectionChanged: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  select(item) {
    this.selectionChanged.emit(item);
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'instituicao-form',
  template: `
<form>
  ...
</form>`,
})
export class InstituicaoForm {
  var item;
  update(value) {
    this.item = value;
  }
}
```

Not tested